# R bypass ssl installing packages

Tags: r, ssl, install.packages

I am at a company that uses an internal registry to host R packages.

`install.packages("bookdown", repos=xxx)` gives me the `unable to access index for repository` error due to self signed certificate in value chain.

I am able to download the tarfile using

`curl -k0 internalrepo/mypackage.tar.gz`
`R CMD INSTALL mypackage.tar.gz`

However I will have to do that for ALL packages and dependencies.

Isn't there a way to force install.packages to use INSECURE curl? I tried changing the `download.file.method` to wget, libcurl, and curl so far without success...

Answer (score 2):

In a similar setting (plus windows), I use options given in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69718474/13776976) inside my .Rprofile and it works:

```
 options(repos = c(CRAN = "internalrepo"),
         download.file.method = "curl",
         download.file.extra = "-k -L")
```

Although it would be much safer to set this for install.packages only and not for download.packages in general.