# R: downloading error 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'

Tags: r

I want to download a png file from a website and the code worked for me before. However, now it keeps showing an error as follows. Can you please help me with this? Thanks  heaps.

```
url1 ="https://niwa.co.nz/static/climate/smd_anom.png?1234"
filename1 <-paste("NiwaSoil_", format(Sys.Date()-1 , "%Y_%m_%d"), ".png",sep="")
download.file(url1,filename1, mode = 'wb'
```

The error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same issue using R 4.2.2. The following command should work:

```
url1 ="https://niwa.co.nz/static/climate/smd_anom.png?1234"
filename1 <-paste("NiwaSoil_", format(Sys.Date()-1 , "%Y_%m_%d"), ".png",sep="")
download.file(url1,filename1, method = "wget", extra = "--no-check-certificate")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to R 4.2 on a computer without internet access using a custom CRAN mirror with a custom certificate.
The solution from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69718474/13776976) worked for me, but I think it should be used with care on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use R 4.2.0, you need to install new Rtools for this version since the previous Rtools wont work with R.4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded via "wget" command, then used locally

```
wget $URL --no-check-certificate
```